# Не слышу музыку через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, музыка

Увидел недавно тут способ проигрывать музыку в Python:

```
import pyglet
sound = pyglet.media.load('ussr.mp3', streaming=False)
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Код запускается без ошибок, но дальше этого фрагмента не идет. И главное - я не слышу звука (микшеры какие угодно проверил, не получилось). Как вернуть звук и нормально запустить код?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена частично, необходимо было убрать аргумент streaming=False и поехало. Но параллельно музыка все равно не идет, и код дальше не работает.

Comment: Если у вас проблема что музыка с остальной частью кода не работает, то разделите их на разные потоки. Тогда код будет идти в своём русле, а музыка в другом. Для этого почитайте о модуле `threading` по этой ссылке: https://python-scripts.com/threading